2002 Honda Odyssey Starter Motor Wiring Troubleshooting
Long story short: friend found his ignition cable unplugged from the terminal on the starter motor. He must have grounded and sorted it while trying to start because his instrument cluster won't light up anymore after that. The 50 amp ignition fuse is blown, at least. What else should I look when I arrive to see his car? What could case the instrument cluster to not light up? Also, emergency lights, windshield wipers and several other non-starting-related functions do not work either. He tells me the fuses are OK. I don't know for sure if he's really looking through the fuses' translucent envelope.
I'm including a picture of the starter motor terminals a diagram of common starter motors.


Edit: added more information about other functions not working properly.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle?
